# Loop Entity when getting data

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities as below:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Code for getting company by Id:

```
    var queryable = await _repository.GetQueryableAsync();
    var companyDto = await queryable
        .Include(x => x.Employees)
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It causes the loop (Company gets Employees, in Employee gets Company, and so on...)

And API cannot response data and show an error 500.

How to deal with this?

Comment: _Do not use Entity Framework entity classes as DTOs_: This is why you need to define separate DTO types.

Comment: Add `AsNoTacking()` to query and EF will stop properties fixup, but as suggested better to use DTO classes.